# show $\sup(\sin(x))=1$ and $\inf(\sin(x))=0$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Can someone help with this:

I have:

$$A = \{ \sin(x)\mid x ∈ {]}0, \pi{[} \,\} $$

I have to find $\inf A$ and $\sup A$.

Comment: I would think about the values that $sin(x)$ attains within that interval.

Comment: Hi. I have a problem proving it. I was trying to prove it by contradiction, so I tried this:

1 is a upper bound for A, since for all x in A, sin(x) <= 1, and then I could maybe assume that sin(x) < 1, and prove it that way?

Comment: Well, what _is_ $A$, first of all? It's the interval $(0, 1]$.

Comment: yeah that's right, but I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have

$$\forall x\in]0,\pi [\;\;0 <\sin(x)\leq1$$

but
$$\sin(\frac {\pi}{2})=1\implies \sup A=1$$
on the other hand
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sin (\frac {1}{n})=0 \;\;\implies \inf A=0.$$